# How can I define an array with a large dimension in HLSL?

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

Is there a way to define a large array in HLSL or any alternative to this as I'm trying to move some of my calculations to the GPU.

I currently have

```
struct Buffer
{
    float3 image[640 * 480];   
};
```

but I am getting the error

```
error X3059: array dimension must be between 1 and 65536
```

It would be great if I didn't have to split this up and then merge them together back on the CPU.

Is there a way around this?

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments, it would make more sense to store this data as a texture, as the array I'm trying to create stores pixel data. I have tried to define my `Texture2D` in the HLSL file, but I can't seem to edit the data, or write to the texture file.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't know much about DirectX/HLSL, but in OpenGL, Uniform Buffers (which this seems to be an analogue to) have similar limits to their storage capacity, and it's usually recommended you use textures as a substitute storage instead (which seems fitting, since this seems to be an object representing an image to begin with), or use a *Shader Storage Buffer*, which can have much larger sizes. I don't know what the DX version of a Shader Storage Buffer is though.

Comment: @Xirema that would make more sense yes. I've just tried using Texture2D but I can't seem to modify the pixel data from the shader. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, in OpenGL, you need to use *Shader Storage Buffers* if you want both read AND write access to the buffer, whereas Uniform Buffers tend to be Read-Only, and textures can only be read when supplied as an object to the shader and only be written to as part of the normal output of the Fragment (Pixel, in HLSL) shader, if you bind a custom Framebuffer with a Texture attachment. Either solution should have an equivalent in HLSL.

Comment: I did a little digging, it sounds like `RWBuffer`s are the HLSL equivalent. I don't know how to write that code, but you probably want to look into that.

Comment: To write pixel data from the shader you need to bind texture as render target.

Comment: I've created a `RWTexture2D` object in the shader and altered the values of it, but how do I get it back to the CPU so I can either display it, or write it to a file?

Comment: Take a look at the [BC6HBC7EncoderCS](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/BC6HBC7EncoderCS) sample for an example of doing compute on a texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this but as I am manipulating image data, using `RWTexture2D<float4>` and providing read write access seems to work fine for what I want to achieve.